# jqPlot messing up on dynamic Arrray

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have a jqPlot pie chart that I am loading by reading an XML file.  However, when I load the array for slices dynamically the pie chart does not render right, when I hard code the array it seems to render correctly.

The code I use to get the array is:

```
function loadSlices(xml)
{
slices = new Array();
$(xml).find("category").each(
    function()
    {
        $(this).find("slice").each(
            function()
            {
                slice = new Array($(this).attr("name"));
                slice.push($(this).attr("size"));
                slices.push(slice);
            }
        );
    }
);
return slices;
 }
```

The code loading the chart is:

```
function pieChart(name,xmlurl)
{
$.get(xmlurl,function(xml)
{

    loadSize(name,xml);
    slices= new Array();
    slices.push(loadSlices(xml));
    $("#debug").append("\nSLICES ARR (getting ready to load):");
    debug2dArray(slices);
    //debug2dArray(slices)
    //now load in the pie chart
    var plot1 = $.jqplot(name,[slices],
        {
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                rendererOptions:{
                    showDataLables: true
                },
            }
    });
});//end get AJAX request
 }
```

When I hard code the slices array as `[[["PB&J",2],["Ham",1]]]` it works perfectly fine.  Any help would be appreciated.

### Updates

#### XML

```
<chart>
    <size width="450px" height="200px"/>
        <category>
              <slice name="PB&J" size="3" />
              <slice name="Ham"  size="1" />
         </category>
 </chart>
```

#### JSFiddles

[Static Array](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgB79/)

Comment: Can you share some code at the http://jsfiddle.net could be even the hard-coded example? So we can start from there. Also please show part of XML or preferably console.log of the slices array before return.

Comment: @Boro I am getting a fiddle started now.  Just need to upload the Javascripts to S3.

Comment: @Boro I have added the JSFiddle.  See question for links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.  When I was loading it the second time it was rendering the second argument in the embeded arrays as a string so `["PB&J","1"]`, which jqPlot did not like.  So adding a parseInt() around the push for the integer resulted in the correct display.  To see a demo of the fix see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgB79/1/).

Comment: +1 you see how making jsfiddles helps :) Happy for you. Go ahead accept your answer when you can. Also for further reference make a jsfiddle presenting the solution.